# Origin of "knife to a gunfight" quote

Tags: dialogue, the-untouchables, origin, the-punisher

I hope this question isn't too tirivial, but in [*The Punisher*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0330793/) *Harry Heck* says to *Frank*

> You are one dumb son of a bitch. Bringing a knife to a gunfight.

right before *Frank* kills him making said knife shoot out from the shaft.

I always understood this quote as a reference to [*The Untouchables*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094226/), when *Malone* (having a gun in hand) says to some thug trying to stab him

> Isn't that just like a wop? Brings a knife to a gun fight.

Just before running into a trap and being gunned down.

1. So first of all is there any source that this is indeed intended as a reference to *The Untouchables* or is it just me drawing a connection where there is none (though the quotes are really similar).
2. And furthermore, is the quote from *The Untouchables* maybe in turn a reference to another (maybe more famous) older movie/story (to which *The Punisher* maybe actually refers, too)?

Comment: Actually, it precedes The Untouchables -- it's in Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid.

Comment: It might first have memorably been said in 1987, buy Spielberg's 'Raiders of the Lost Ark' acted it out in 1981.

Comment: I thought it was "Bringing" in The Untouchables as well.

Comment: @N.Presley I don't know where I got it from, I think the IMDb quotes page. But thanks for noticing, I'll try to check the transcript or even the actual scene.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it comes from *The Untouchables* film.

### Films

According to searches at [Subzin](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?q=knife%20gunfight), *The Untouchables* was the first with this line, but has been emulated in at least 20 other films since 2000.

- *The Untouchables* (1987)
  01:21:23 Brings a knife to a gunfight.
- *The Target Shoots First* (2000)
  00:17:38 What are you doing, Max? Bringing a knife to a gunfight?
- *Shottas* (2002)
  00:18:22 what are you doing, max? bringing a knife to a gunfight?
- *Duplex* (2003)
  01:17:10 Who are ya, bringing a knife to a gunfight?
- *The Punisher* (2004)
  01:06:55 Bring a knife to a gunfight.
- *Waist Deep* (2006)
  00:33:12 Nigga, don't bring a knife to a gunfight, my...
- *BloodRayne II: Deliverance* (2007)
  00:28:09 Ain't it like an Irishman
  to bring a bottle to a gunfight.
- *Dod vid ankomst* (2008)
  00:59:29 How typical of you, bringing a knife to a gun fight.
- *Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull* (2008)
  Nice try kid, but I think you just brought a knife. To a gunfight.
- *The Boondock Saints II: All Saints Day* (2009)
  00:35:47 That's like bringing a knife to a gunfight. / Yeah, or like bringing a really small gun to a gunfight.
- *The Good Guy* (2009)
  00:37:24 Never take a knife to a gunfight, mate.
- *Wonderful World* (2009)
  00:26:00 Never bring a knife to a gunfight.
- *Death Hunter* (2010)
  00:50:49 Just like a rookie to bring a knife to a gun fight.

Including some variations on the theme:

- *The Glimmer Man* (1996)
  00:16:59 It's kind of like takin' a screwdriver to a gunfight.
- *Black Cat Run* (1998)
  00:32:40 A crow bar to a gun fight? Drop the fucking crowbar.
- *Urban Justice* (2007)
  01:27:07 l know you ain't dumb enough to bring a fist to a gunfight.
- *G-Force* (2009)
  01:12:27 [Speckles] Just like humans. Bringing guns to a space junk fight.
- *Unrivaled* (2010)
  00:28:46 you brought a knife to a bottle fight.
- *Cross* (2011)
  00:08:06 Genius. Brings sticks to a gunfight.

### Books

*The Untouchables* film is based on the 1957 book of the same name, but it doesn't seem like the quote comes from the book.

The first use of the phrase I could find in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22knife%20to%20a%20gunfight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20gun%20fight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20shootout%22&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&biw=930&bih=462&sa=X&ei=SQrTT9PRB4qK4gSWiZG2Aw&ved=0CDcQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:,cd_max:12/31/1990&tbm=bks) is in 1989, after the film came out: in a [fishing magazine](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22knife%20to%20a%20gunfight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20gun%20fight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20shootout%22&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&biw=930&bih=462&sa=X&ei=SQrTT9PRB4qK4gSWiZG2Aw&ved=0CDcQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:,cd_max:12/31/1990&tbm=bks) and a book called *[Texas Wit and Wisdom](http://books.google.com/books?id=jL-B-Zqwu6MC&q=%22knife%20to%20a%20gunfight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20gun%20fight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20shootout%22&dq=%22knife%20to%20a%20gunfight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20gun%20fight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20shootout%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XArTT6jzFMbm4QTw7_CxAw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAg)*). It does sound like it could be a Texas phrase.

This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knife%20to%20a%20gunfight,knife%20to%20a%20gun%20fight&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows nothing before 1987:

[image: Ngram]

### Newspapers

Likewise, the first use I found in [Google News](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22knife%20to%20a%20gunfight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20gun%20fight%22%20OR%20%22knife%20to%20a%20shootout%22&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&gl=us&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1990,sbd:1&tbm=nws&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=kQ3TT9T3OI2B4AT29aCOAw&ved=0CDcQpwUoAQ&biw=930&bih=462) is from June 24, 1987 in the *[Argus Press](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=mV8iAAAAIBAJ&sjid=AqsFAAAAIBAJ&pg=2959,4795026&dq=knife-to-a-gunfight%20%7C%20knife-to-a-gun-fight%20%7C%20knife-to-a-shootout&hl=en)*'s review of *The Untouchables*.

> ### 'Untouchables:' It's a Brilliant Movie Destined To Be a Classic
>
> ...
>
> He [Sean Connery] has lots of great lines as Ness's mentor but the best one is when he tells Ness right away the first rule of police work:
>
> "Make sure when your shift is over you go home alive."
>
> Another is when, fighting for his life, he cracks:
>
> "Leave it to a ... to bring a knife to a gunfight."

Comment: A saying from [1732](http://books.google.fi/books?id=3y8JAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=musket&f=false): *Take not a Musket to kill a Butterfly.*

Comment: Great answer, however I do keep wondering if it's not a common expression (so not neccesarily from a movie or book)..

Comment: @Hugo that quote from 1732 is something completely different.

Comment: @poepje: Yes, that's why the 1732 quote is a comment and not in my answer.

Comment: @poepje: The Ngram chart, with zero results before 1987, suggests it wasn't a common expression before The Untouchables (1987).

Comment: @Hugo That's because Ngram looks in pdf books, not worldwide common knowledge. The internet doesn't know EVERYTHING...

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong, however I think that expression was first used in the movie "Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid" Robert Redford & Paul Newman 1969

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.